# How do I call a function in HTML in a Javascript file?

Tags: javascript

I have a function in HTML that I want to be able to call, but I don't know how to call it.

Inside the HTML script I have a function named CreateCard that is created at the end of the script.

Inside another script (my webserver), I'm trying to call it like this:

```js
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
  fs.readFile('./https/home.html', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("ERROR, ERROR")
      res.writeHead(404)
      res.write('Error | File Not Found')
    } else {
      res.write(data)

      let limiteds = GetLimiteds()
      limiteds.forEach((itemData) => {
        if (client.get(GetKey(itemData.itemID, itemData.itemClassName)) && client.get(GetKey(itemData.itemID, itemData.itemClassName)) != 0) {
          data.CreateCard(itemData.itemName, itemData.itemClassName, itemData.itemID, client.get(GetKey(itemData.itemID, itemData.itemClassName)), itemData.MaxAllowed)
        }
      })
    }
    res.end()
  })
});
```

How can you call the function inside the JavaScript file?

Comment: You have a function at the client and you want to call it from the server. Not possible.

Answer (score 1):

A JavaScript program embedded in an HTML document is a **different program** to a JavaScript program that creates an HTTP server and responds to HTTP requests.

This is true even if the HTML document program 1 is embedded in is created by program 2.

You can't call a function in one program from another.

The server can output `<script> nameOfFunction() </script>` in the HTML it is generating.

The client side program can use XMLHttpRequest / fetch / etc to make an HTTP request to the server.

Those are (more-or-less) the limits.

Comment: I need to use this in another script since HTML scripts can't require Redis (the datastore I use) or fs (idk if it can't it just didn't let me) @Quentin

Comment: @SpencerIsCool — Your needs cannot change reality. If you need to access the file system or a database then do it with server side code.

Comment: I have server side code, its just I can't call the HTML from the JavaScript file

Comment: @SpencerIsCool — No, you can't. As I said, you need to generate the HTML you actually want from the server side code.